# Orthogonal Complement of the $\pi(H)$-invariant Vectors in a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, group-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $H \le G$ be an inclusion of countable, discrete groups, and let $\pi$ be unitary representation of $G$ on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{K}$. Is it possible to determine the orthogonal complete $(\mathcal{K}^{H})^{\perp}$, where $\mathcal{K}^{H} := \{ \xi \in \mathcal{K} : \pi(h) \xi = \xi ~~ \forall h \in H \}$ denotes the closed subspace of $\pi(H)$-invariant vectors in $\mathcal{K}$? That is, does this orthogonal complement admit another description aside from the one stating that $(\mathcal{K}^H)^\perp$ consists of all those vectors which are orthogonal to all the vectors in $\mathcal{K}^H$?

Comment: I do not think it might be useful: $(\mathcal{K}^H)^\perp$ is the maximal $\pi(H)$-invariant subspace, which does not contain nonzero $\pi(H)$-invariant vectors.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc No, that's a nice alternative characterization. Thank you for that!

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Actually, something is confusing me a bit. If $(\mathcal{K}^H)^\perp$ were a maximal $\pi(H)$-invariant subspace, wouldn't that mean $\mathcal{K}^H \subseteq (\mathcal{K}^H)^\perp$ or something contradictory like that?

Comment: In my comment it is a maximal $\pi(\mathcal{H})$-invariant subspace not containing  $\pi(\mathcal{H})$-invariant  vectors.